# @html.hidden not persist custom property model after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, postback

I'm using a razor mvc view with a `@Html.HiddenFor()`, but after postback a custom property value of model always returns `null`.

Property: `public Survey Survey { get; set; }`

Here my hidden field:

```
@html.HiddenFor(x => x.Survey);
```

Here my Model:

```
public class Response
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    public Survey Survey { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Thanks, Jorge

Comment: `Survey` is a complex object and you cannot bind an input to a complex object (look at the html it generates - it has `value="yourAssembly.Survey"`). You need to generate an input for each property of `Survey`. But that would be crazy. You not editing it so do not send it back again. All you need to save the data is the value of property `SurveyId`, and if for some other reason, you need the `Survey`, then get it again from the database based on the value of `SurveyId`

Comment: But what is your `@Html.hiddenValueFor()` method (a typo, or do you have a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method)?

Comment: Stephen, the correct htmlhelper is @html.HiddenFor(x => x.Survey); I 've just modified the original question, thanks

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was a typo :)

Comment: Ok, so the correct way is to persist ID and not object, thanks